# find time slot in range of datetime

Tags: python, datetime

guys i am struggling to implement this, i have a start date, end date and a list of tuples of datetime ranges, and then i have a an event for like 30 minutes, i want to check where that event could be placed between the above time range

```py
start = datetime(2022, 5, 19, 7, 0)
end = start + timedelta(hours=3.5)
x = c.get_event_detail(start, end)
print(start)
print(x)
print(end)
```

output:

```
2022-05-19 07:00:00
[(datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 19, 9, 30), datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 19, 11, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 19, 9, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 19, 10, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 19, 7, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 19, 9, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 19, 7, 30), datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 19, 8, 15))]
2022-05-19 10:30:00
```

well i tried to add start and end and convert them into list then sort then iterate over them but the issue is that the some ending part of the tuple has ovverride dateranges, for example (6:00 pm to 8 pm and 7 pm to 8 pm)
the event is just an event with title and a duration and i want to check where it can be placed in the given range, its a part of my program, so i picked the relavant code only.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you have more details about the event?

Comment: plz see edited post

Comment: Then you can write your program to handle what you're trying to do. It doesn't make sense to fill the list with starting times with difference of 15 min or 30 min. What if some event takes only 3 min?!

Comment: I've written systems exactly for that, and can tell you the solution *can* become fairly complex depending on your requirements and desired features. As a first step though, you'll want to use an appropriate data structure to deal with time ranges, otherwise your code will become even more complex. https://pypi.org/project/intervaltree/ is a fine library for this, which allows you to query time ranges and manipulate them, including checking for overlaps and merging overlapping ranges. You should start with that, and come back when you have more specific questions.

Comment: @deceze alright sir, i ll check that and if i get an issue, ill tag u so u can help me thanks :D

Comment: @deceze can u plz guild me a bit,

Comment: *Welcome into the association of programmers!*

Comment: Oh, did you mean "guide"?

Comment: yes, coz the library is a bit confusing, i cant get what i want

Comment: i just simply want timestamp of given duration which can fit in between start and stop. if true

Comment: @deceze sir ...